# How to Deploy and Configure an MVC3 application using IIS6

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-6

I have created an application installer for my MVC3 project and have followed the BIN Deployment suggestions found online.

My site has been installed but I don't get any pages displayed.

This is how the VS2010 installer project looks

[image: This is how the VS2010 installer project looks]

and this is how I have IIS setup
[image]

How do you get the Home Index page to be the default page as it is when I run the application through Visual studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS 6.0 doesn't support extensionless urls out of the box. This means that if you try to navigate to `/Home/Index`, IIS 6.0 doesn't know that this is an ASP.NET application and nothing happens. Extensionless urls are supported out of the box starting from IIS 7.0 when running the application in managed pipeline mode.

You will need to associate the unmanaged `aspnet_isapi.dll` filter with ASP.NET if you want to achieve that. Phil Haack covered how this topic in [his blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/12/22/asp-net-mvc-3-extensionless-urls-on-iis-6.aspx) (ASP.NET 4.0) and [this post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx) (for CLR 2.0, which is not your case since you are using ASP.NET MVC 3).

Comment: I've followed the how-to guides and I'm now getting the 403 error. It's a step forward but the suggested actions to resolve the issue aren't work. I'm starting to think the simplest option would be to get the company to upgrade to server 2008.